# matlab SVM returns NaN

Tags: classification, svm, matlab

here's my problem: I'm trying to classify some data with Support Vector Machine, specifically the MATLAB implementation fitcsvm. However, when I compute the prediction, some of the predictions' posterior probabilities are set to NaN. What does that mean? Here's the code

```
% Training
model  = fitcsvm(trainX, trainY, 'KernelFunction', 'RBF', 'KernelScale', 'auto', 'Prior', 'empirical');
model = fitSVMPosterior(model, 'Leaveout', 'on');

% Prediction
[~,scores] = predict(model, testX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `testX` contains `NaN`s. If `testX` contains an `NaN` for any variable used as an SVM term, the posterior probability will also be `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

It is described here that this can be due to a VPN software running in parallel:

[https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f427](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f427)

> Q: Why the code gives NaN (not a number) results?
>
> This rarely happens, but few users reported the problem. It seems that
> their computers for training libsvm have the VPN client running. The
> VPN software has some bugs and causes this problem. Please try to
> close or disconnect the VPN client.